# how to print the last login time in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

For example, I use `last | grep pts/ | awk '{print $1 " "$4 " "$5 " "$6 " "$7}' > who_log.txt`  to get the login information:

```
samuelli Fri Apr 24 19:51
pi Fri Apr 24 19:50
liuly Fri Apr 24 19:50
pi Fri Apr 24 19:46
liuly Fri Apr 24 18:49
pi Fri Apr 24 18:48
pi Fri Apr 24 18:46
```

But I only want it to print the latest login time for each user,
like :

```
samuelli Fri Apr 24 19:51
liuly Fri Apr 24 19:50
pi Fri Apr 24 19:46
```

I could I do in shell script ?

Comment: Do you have the `lastlog` command?  Can that help?

Comment: lastlog will show all users' login information, even that user never login in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

`last | grep pts/ | awk '{ if (users[$1] != 1) { users[$1]=1; print $1 " "$4 " "$5 " "$6 " "$7} }'`

more simpler:
`last | awk '/pts/ && !users[$1] {print $1, $4, $5, $6, $7; users[$1]=1; }'`

Comment: You can drop the `grep` and do all the processing in `awk`: `awk '(/pts\//){ if (users[$1] != 1) { users[$1]=1; print $1 " "$4 " "$5 " "$6 " "$7} }'`

Comment: Still simpler:  `last | awk '/pts\// && !users[$1] { users[$1]=1; print $1,$4,$5,$6,$7}'`

Comment: Don't I have to compare the time for each user ? It seems you only compare the username, but not compare the time.

Comment: `last` is sorted. That's why we only compare `user`.